# Why does the current equation in mesh 4 i.e I4 negative?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

Why does the current equation in mesh 4 i.e I4 negative??

[image]

Comment: Notice that I1 is positive because it is flowing in the same direction as 4A current source. But I4 is negative because of the 3A current source flow in the opposite direction to the I4 (I4 is an assumed mesh "virtual current") current.

Comment: This is why I prefer KCL over KVL. No confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when beginning to calculate that all the currents in the answer are **assumed** to run clockwise around the loops.

If the numerical answer shows a negative sign it just means that, in fact, the current is running in the opposite direction to your assumption - anti-clockwise in this case.

Comment: So why is the current flowing in anticlockwise direction?? Because according to the circuit both the current sources have same direction

Comment: "... both the current sources ..." There are three, I1, I2 and I4. Which are you referring to? Note that I4 is a great big 3 A current source pointing anti-clockwise on loop 4.

Comment: @JuveriaAnsari You need to compare the arrow inside the symbol for the current source with the arrow for the mesh current. If they are pointing in different directions then the mesh current is the negative of the source current.